# Position of tabularx-table

Tags: tabularx, multicol

I am trying to do a landscape document with a few (fake) barcodes in 3 columns. The data is within a table. Problem now is that in the 2nd col the table leaves a lot of space to its section header – I cannot seem to fix the position.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        landscape,
        left=1cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=1cm,
        bottom=1cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}


\def\barcode#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\begingroup%
  \dimen0=0.1em
  \def\stack##1##2{\oalign{##1\cr\hidewidth##2\hidewidth}}%
  \def\0##1{\kern##1\dimen0}%
  \def\1##1{\vrule height5ex width##1\dimen0}%
  \def\L##1{\ifcase##1\bc3211##1\or\bc2221##1\or\bc2122##1\or\bc1411##1%
    \or\bc1132##1\or\bc1231##1\or\bc1114##1\or\bc1312##1\or\bc1213##1%
    \or\bc3112##1\fi}%
  \def\R##1{\bgroup\let\next\1\let\1\0\let\0\next\L##1\egroup}%
  \def\G##1{\bgroup\let\bc\bcg\L##1\egroup}% reverse
  \def\bc##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##1\1##2\0##3\1##4}##5}%
  \def\bcg##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##4\1##3\0##2\1##1}##5}%
  \def\bcR##1##2##3##4##5##6{\R##1\R##2\R##3\R##4\R##5\R##6\11\01\11\09%
    \endgroup}%
  \stack{\09}#1\11\01\11\L#2%
  \ifcase#1\L#3\L#4\L#5\L#6\L#7\or\L#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\G#7%
    \or\L#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\G#7\or\L#3\G#4\G#5\G#6\L#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\L#5\G#6\G#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\L#7\or\G#3\L#4\G#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\G#5\G#6\L#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\L#7%
  \fi\01\11\01\11\01\bcR}

\begin{document}

\section*{Virtuelles Lager - \"Ubersicht Barcodes}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\subsection*{CPU}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|}
\hline
MacBook 12"                 & \barcode 8793462789110 \\\hline
MacBook Air 11"         & \barcode 8793462789111 \\\hline
MacBook Air 13"             & \barcode 8793462789112 \\\hline
MacBook Pro 13"         & \barcode 8793462789113 \\\hline
MacBook Pro 15"         & \barcode 8793462789114 \\\hline
iMac 21"                        & \barcode 8793462789115 \\\hline
iMac 27"                        & \barcode 8793462789116 \\\hline
iMac Pro                        & \barcode 8793462789117 \\\hline
Mac Pro                     & \barcode 8793462789118 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\columnbreak

\subsection*{iOS}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|}
\hline
iPad 9.7"                           & \barcode 8793462789120 \\\hline
iPad Pro 10.5"                  & \barcode 8793462789121 \\\hline
iPad    Pro 12.9"                   & \barcode 8793462789122 \\\hline
iPhone SE                       & \barcode 8793462789123 \\\hline
iPhone 8                            & \barcode 8793462789124 \\\hline
iPhone 8 Plus                   & \barcode 8793462789125 \\\hline
iPhone X                            & \barcode 8793462789126  \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\columnbreak

\subsection*{Zubeh\"or}
%\begin{table}    % Embedding to table env results in not showing the tabularx at all...
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[!H]{|X|c|}
\hline
iPhone X Case  & \barcode 8793462789130\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
%\end{table}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill the columns before breaking:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
  landscape,
  left=1cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=1cm,
  bottom=1cm,
  % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
  % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
  % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}

\def\barcode#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\begingroup%
  \dimen0=0.1em
  \def\stack##1##2{\oalign{##1\cr\hidewidth##2\hidewidth}}%
  \def\0##1{\kern##1\dimen0}%
  \def\1##1{\vrule height5ex width##1\dimen0}%
  \def\L##1{\ifcase##1\bc3211##1\or\bc2221##1\or\bc2122##1\or\bc1411##1%
    \or\bc1132##1\or\bc1231##1\or\bc1114##1\or\bc1312##1\or\bc1213##1%
    \or\bc3112##1\fi}%
  \def\R##1{\bgroup\let\next\1\let\1\0\let\0\next\L##1\egroup}%
  \def\G##1{\bgroup\let\bc\bcg\L##1\egroup}% reverse
  \def\bc##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##1\1##2\0##3\1##4}##5}%
  \def\bcg##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##4\1##3\0##2\1##1}##5}%
  \def\bcR##1##2##3##4##5##6{\R##1\R##2\R##3\R##4\R##5\R##6\11\01\11\09%
    \endgroup}%
  \stack{\09}#1\11\01\11\L#2%
  \ifcase#1\L#3\L#4\L#5\L#6\L#7\or\L#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\G#7%
    \or\L#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\G#7\or\L#3\G#4\G#5\G#6\L#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\L#5\G#6\G#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\L#7\or\G#3\L#4\G#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\G#5\G#6\L#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\L#7%
  \fi\01\11\01\11\01\bcR}

\begin{document}

\section*{Virtuelles Lager - \"Ubersicht Barcodes}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\subsection*{CPU}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|}
\hline
MacBook 12"       & \barcode 8793462789110 \\\hline
MacBook Air 11"   & \barcode 8793462789111 \\\hline
MacBook Air 13"   & \barcode 8793462789112 \\\hline
MacBook Pro 13"   & \barcode 8793462789113 \\\hline
MacBook Pro 15"   & \barcode 8793462789114 \\\hline
iMac 21"          & \barcode 8793462789115 \\\hline
iMac 27"          & \barcode 8793462789116 \\\hline
iMac Pro          & \barcode 8793462789117 \\\hline
Mac Pro           & \barcode 8793462789118 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak

\subsection*{iOS}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|}
\hline
iPad 9.7"         & \barcode 8793462789120 \\\hline
iPad Pro 10.5"    & \barcode 8793462789121 \\\hline
iPad    Pro 12.9" & \barcode 8793462789122 \\\hline
iPhone SE         & \barcode 8793462789123 \\\hline
iPhone 8          & \barcode 8793462789124 \\\hline
iPhone 8 Plus     & \barcode 8793462789125 \\\hline
iPhone X          & \barcode 8793462789126  \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak

\subsection*{Zubeh\"or}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[!H]{|X|c|}
\hline
iPhone X Case  & \barcode 8793462789130\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace*{\fill}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although other answers work as well, this solution seems to be the simplest to me. Learned something about floating as well, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Package `multicol` tries to balance the columns. Therefore the stretchable space between the subsection title and the table is stretched to fill the page.
The balancing can be turned off by `\raggedcolumns`:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\raggedcolumns
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `multicol` package, you could use the `paracol` package which allows for multicolumn documents whith 'synchronized' columns.

Applied to your example, you would just have to replace `\usepackage{multicol}` by `\usepackage{paracol}`, `\begin{multicols}{3}` by `\begin{paracol}{3}` and `\columnbreak` by `\swithcolumn` respectively:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        landscape,
        left=1cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=1cm,
        bottom=1cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %<------------

\usepackage{paracol}%<--------------

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}


\def\barcode#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\begingroup%
  \dimen0=0.1em
  \def\stack##1##2{\oalign{##1\cr\hidewidth##2\hidewidth}}%
  \def\0##1{\kern##1\dimen0}%
  \def\1##1{\vrule height5ex width##1\dimen0}%
  \def\L##1{\ifcase##1\bc3211##1\or\bc2221##1\or\bc2122##1\or\bc1411##1%
    \or\bc1132##1\or\bc1231##1\or\bc1114##1\or\bc1312##1\or\bc1213##1%
    \or\bc3112##1\fi}%
  \def\R##1{\bgroup\let\next\1\let\1\0\let\0\next\L##1\egroup}%
  \def\G##1{\bgroup\let\bc\bcg\L##1\egroup}% reverse
  \def\bc##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##1\1##2\0##3\1##4}##5}%
  \def\bcg##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##4\1##3\0##2\1##1}##5}%
  \def\bcR##1##2##3##4##5##6{\R##1\R##2\R##3\R##4\R##5\R##6\11\01\11\09%
    \endgroup}%
  \stack{\09}#1\11\01\11\L#2%
  \ifcase#1\L#3\L#4\L#5\L#6\L#7\or\L#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\G#7%
    \or\L#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\G#7\or\L#3\G#4\G#5\G#6\L#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\L#5\G#6\G#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\L#7\or\G#3\L#4\G#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\G#5\G#6\L#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\L#7%
  \fi\01\11\01\11\01\bcR}

\begin{document}

%\pagestyle{empty} %<-----------------
\section*{Virtuelles Lager - Übersicht Barcodes}
\begin{paracol}{3}%<-----------
\subsection*{CPU}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|}
\hline
MacBook 12"                 & \barcode 8793462789110 \\\hline
MacBook Air 11"         & \barcode 8793462789111 \\\hline
MacBook Air 13"             & \barcode 8793462789112 \\\hline
MacBook Pro 13"         & \barcode 8793462789113 \\\hline
MacBook Pro 15"         & \barcode 8793462789114 \\\hline
iMac 21"                        & \barcode 8793462789115 \\\hline
iMac 27"                        & \barcode 8793462789116 \\\hline
iMac Pro                        & \barcode 8793462789117 \\\hline
Mac Pro                     & \barcode 8793462789118 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\switchcolumn %<--------------

\subsection*{iOS}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|}
\hline
iPad 9.7"                           & \barcode 8793462789120 \\\hline
iPad Pro 10.5"                  & \barcode 8793462789121 \\\hline
iPad    Pro 12.9"                   & \barcode 8793462789122 \\\hline
iPhone SE                       & \barcode 8793462789123 \\\hline
iPhone 8                            & \barcode 8793462789124 \\\hline
iPhone 8 Plus                   & \barcode 8793462789125 \\\hline
iPhone X                            & \barcode 8793462789126  \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\switchcolumn %<----------------


\subsection*{Zubehör}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[!H]{|X|c|}
\hline
iPhone X Case  & \barcode 8793462789130\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{paracol} %<----------------
\end{document}
```

I have also replaced `\"U` by `Ü` and `\"o` by `ö`. With the 2018 release of LaTeX, UTF-8 is the new default input encoding which enabes you to directly type umlauts. With older releases, you would need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in oder to compile the above example.

Since you reduce the bottom margin of your page quite much, you might have noticed tat the page numbers gets amost cut off. If you don't want the pages to be numbered, you could use `\pagestyle{empty}` as shown in the example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler to use a single `tabularx` and `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage
[ a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        landscape,
        left=1cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=1cm,
        bottom=1cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\def\barcode#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\begingroup%
  \dimen0=0.1em
  \def\stack##1##2{\oalign{##1\cr\hidewidth##2\hidewidth}}%
  \def\0##1{\kern##1\dimen0}%
  \def\1##1{\vrule height5ex width##1\dimen0}%
  \def\L##1{\ifcase##1\bc3211##1\or\bc2221##1\or\bc2122##1\or\bc1411##1%
    \or\bc1132##1\or\bc1231##1\or\bc1114##1\or\bc1312##1\or\bc1213##1%
    \or\bc3112##1\fi}%
  \def\R##1{\bgroup\let\next\1\let\1\0\let\0\next\L##1\egroup}%
  \def\G##1{\bgroup\let\bc\bcg\L##1\egroup}% reverse
  \def\bc##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##1\1##2\0##3\1##4}##5}%
  \def\bcg##1##2##3##4##5{\stack{\0##4\1##3\0##2\1##1}##5}%
  \def\bcR##1##2##3##4##5##6{\R##1\R##2\R##3\R##4\R##5\R##6\11\01\11\09%
    \endgroup}%
  \stack{\09}#1\11\01\11\L#2%
  \ifcase#1\L#3\L#4\L#5\L#6\L#7\or\L#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\G#7%
    \or\L#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\G#7\or\L#3\G#4\G#5\G#6\L#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\L#5\G#6\G#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\G#4\G#5\L#6\L#7\or\G#3\L#4\G#5\L#6\G#7%
    \or\G#3\L#4\G#5\G#6\L#7\or\G#3\G#4\L#5\G#6\L#7%
  \fi\01\11\01\11\01\bcR}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\section*{Virtuelles Lager - \"Ubersicht Barcodes}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|c|X|c|c|X|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\large\bfseries CPU} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5mm}}{} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\large\bfseries iOS} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5mm}}{} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\large\bfseries Zubehör}\\[1ex]
\hhline{|--|~|--|~|--|}
MacBook 12" & \barcode 8793462789110 & & iPad 9.7" & \barcode 8793462789120 & & iPhone X Case & \barcode 8793462789130\\
\hhline{|--|~|--|~--|}
MacBook Air 11" & \barcode 8793462789111 & & iPad Pro 10.5" & \barcode 8793462789121 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
\hhline{|--|~|--|~~~}
MacBook Air 13" & \barcode 8793462789112 & & iPad Pro 12.9" & \barcode 8793462789122 \\
\hhline{|--|~|--|~~~}
MacBook Pro 13" & \barcode 8793462789113 & & iPhone SE & \barcode 8793462789123 \\
\hhline{|--|~|--|~~~}
MacBook Pro 15" & \barcode 8793462789114 & & iPhone 8 & \barcode 8793462789124 \\
\hhline{|--|~|--|~~~}
iMac 21" & \barcode 8793462789115 & & iPhone 8 Plus & \barcode 8793462789125 \\
\hhline{|--|~|--|~~~}
iMac 27" & \barcode 8793462789116 & & iPhone X & \barcode 8793462789126 \\
\hhline{|--|~|--|~~~}
iMac Pro & \barcode 8793462789117 \\
\hhline{|--|*6~}
Mac Pro & \barcode 8793462789118 \\
\hhline{|--|*6~}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]